# use data slicer to distinct count in DAX PowerBI Desktop

Tags: powerbi, dax, distinct

I have two columns Month and ID a want distinc count per each month, but once I use data slicer to show data it shows as count distinct per select period

For example I have

[I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14VHQ.png)

I used :
COUNT_ID =  distinctcount('ID'[DATA])

once I select in data slicer 202207 & 202208 I get distinct values 4:

[WANT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2m8D.png)

but I want result 5 because

202207 distinct values 2
202208 distinct values 3

I want to use this logic for whole data set once I select specific period.
Has anybody can help with?

Answer (score 0):

```
Ids =
SUMX (
    VALUES ( 'Table'[Month] ),
    CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[ID] ) )
)
```